# Doctrine persist & flush causes duplicate records in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I call persist & flush on `PersonalDevelopmentRequest` entity it causes presence of duplicate record in DB.

I use PHP 7.0.7, MySQL 5.6.28 and Symfony 2.8.7.

**UPDATE:** When I remove redirect at the end of controller, Doctrine persists record only once. Can redirect relates with Doctrine?

Code in controller:

```
$request = new PersonalDevelopmentRequest();
$request
    ->setTrainingGroup($training->getTrainingGroup())
    ->setTraining($training)
    ->setEmployee($this->getUser())
    ->setName($training->getName());

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$em->persist($request);
$em->flush();

$this->addFlash('success', 'Mám to.');

return $this->redirectToRoute('personal_development');
```

Entity:

```
/**
 * PersonalDevelopmentRequest.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="personal_development_request")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PersonalDevelopmentRequestRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable()
 */
class PersonalDevelopmentRequest implements WorkflowInterface
{
    use BlameableEntity;
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $period;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="personalDevelopmentRequests")
     */
    private $employee;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $employeeForRelation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TrainingGroup", inversedBy="requests")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $trainingGroup;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Training", inversedBy="requests")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $training;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\AnnualReview", inversedBy="requests")
     */
    private $annualReview;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    const TYPE_ANNUAL_REVIEW = 'annual_review';
    const TYPE_MANUAL = 'manual';
    const TYPE_TRAINING_PLAN = 'training_plan';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=16)
     */
    private $type;

    const STATE_SENT = 'sent';
    const STATE_DECLINED = 'declined';
    const STATE_APPROVED = 'approved';
    const STATE_FINISHED = 'finished';
    const STATE_UNFINISHED = 'unfinished';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=16)
     */
    private $state;

    const RESULT_DIDNT_COMPLETE = 0;
    const RESULT_COMPLETED_PASSED = 1;
    const RESULT_COMPLETED_FAILED = 2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $result;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $cost;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $mustBeRenewedAfter;

    const TRAINING_TYPE_NONE = null;
    const TRAINING_TYPE_INT = 'int';
    const TRAINING_TYPE_EXT = 'ext';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $trainingType;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $rangeInHours;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Log")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="personal_development_request_logs",
     *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="personal_development_request_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="log_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     */
    private $logs;

  ...
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us the name and route  of your controller ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was caused because of duplicating `$kernel->handle($request);` in `app.php`.

Answer (score 0):

with the given code i can only guess that your code block that persists to the database is not inside a conditional block (not within an if condition) and with your update you said that if you remove the `redirectToRoute` it solves it. so it might be a loop of redirection and you might be going to the same controller twice and persisting it twice, i would suggest putting it inside an if condition like a `$form->isValid()` condition for example to avoid freely persisting the records

Comment: I posted whole action, there is no form. It really seems like redirectToRoute causes it from some reason.